# How to define belongsTo relationship in Laravel factory?

Tags: php, laravel, database-testing

I have a Post, User and Country model.

A Post **belongsTo**  as User . A User **belongsTo** a Country.

Is there any way to call the User and Country factory from after the post factory ?

Sort of like

```
factory(Post::class,10)
    ->create()
    ->each(function($post){
       $post
            ->user()
            ->save(
                  factory(User::class)
                      ->create(['some_column' => 'with_some_custom_data'])        
                      ->each(function($user){
                          $user
                              ->country()
                              ->save(
                                  factory(Country::class)
                                  ->create(['name' => 'some_custom_name']);
                               );
                        });
                 );
            }
      });
```

**->save()** does not work with **belongsTo** .

using **Larave 7.2**

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

needed to use `relation_column_id` as factory.

so

```php
// post factory 

[
 ... 
 'user_id' => factory(User)->create(),
]

// user factory 
[
  ...
  'country_id' => factory(Country)->create()
]
```